# The definition of proper morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

By [this notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mmustata/Chapter5_631.pdf), a morphism of varieties $f: X \to Y$ is proper if for every morphism
$g: Z \to Y$, the induced morphism $X\times_Y Z\to Z$ is closed, in other words, it's universally closed.

But a morphism of schemes is proper if it is separated, of finite type, and universally closed.

I wonder why there two definitions are coherent? Why do we need to add separated and of finite type for the schemes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mustata is assuming his varieties are separated schemes of finite type over a field. This implies that every morphism of these varieties is of finite type and separated: if $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are morphisms with $g\circ f$ separated (resp. finite type), then $f$ is separated (resp. finite type). This applies to our situation by letting $Z$ be the spectrum of the field we're working over. So Mustata's definition is the same as the usual definition.

As to your question about why we want to "add" separated and of finite type for the scheme side, this is somewhat backwards - this is the typical definition one takes, Mustata just doesn't need to say either of finite type or separated, because the restriction on the types of varieties he's working with already imply that all morphisms of varieties he considers have these properties.

Comment: But I think Mustata doesn't consider his varieties as schemes but just affine or projective varieties. If under this setting, do we have the same thing?

Comment: Your claim that "Mustata doesn't consider his varieties as schemes but just affine or projective varieties" is not correct, see [this previous entry](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mmustata/Chapter3_631.pdf) in his lecture notes for the same class.

Comment: I see, that marks sense

Comment: I have one more question, the universally closed is equivalent to compact in the Hausdorff topological space, here in the scheme case, we add separated for the Haursforr, but we do we need finite type?

Comment: First of all, there are finiteness conditions in the topological case: the target ought to be locally compact Hausdorff for proper to be the same as universally closed. Next, what do you mean, "need"? One can certainly consider separated, universally closed morphisms, but they do not have some of the nice properties that proper morphisms have. For instance, in a proper morphism, the direct image of a coherent sheaf is coherent, but this is not necessarily true for universally closed + separated, as the example of $\coprod^\infty X\to X$ shows.

Comment: @KReiser I agree with everything you said, but just a nitpick : I don't think $\coprod^\infty X\to X$ is closed.

Comment: @Roland Thanks, and you're right, it's not closed in general - I went too fast there and goofed. How about if $X$ is a geometric point - that should be closed, yes?

Comment: @KReiser Yes but not universally closed since the "universal" condition mean that you can consider its pullback along any scheme (not just field extension).

Comment: @Roland thank you for again pointing out my mistake - I don't have my head on straight right now :(. Here's my final offer: $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots]/(x_1,\cdots)^2\to\operatorname{Spec} k$. This is (unless I've goofed again) a separated universal homeomorphism, thus separated and universally closed, but not of finite type. If this is wrong too, I'll just come back in the morning and try again.

Comment: @KReiser Yes I believe it works. You can also take $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}\to\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q}$. My impression, but surely wrong, is that universally closed is the condition for the topological side and finite type the condition for the algebraic side.

Comment: @Roland I think your impression has merit. The example with the fields is nice - I had not thought of that. Thank you for the productive discussion.